# Indicating an en dash in arXiv submission's metadata

Tags: mathematics, arxiv, formatting, online-publication, preprint

As indicated [here](https://arxiv.org/help/prep), arXiv metadata fields (e.g., title or abstract) only accept ASCII input, certain TEX accent commands and "some mathjax", but there are ways of making other symbols appear.

My question is, what is the "best" or "standard" way to indicate an en dash?

From a very quick search, most authors seem to use a hyphen `-`; others use a double hyphen `--`. But these are not the proper ways of showing an en dash.

Comment: If you can only use ASCII, what other options are there?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains the answer.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen

Comment: I would say that it doesn't matter much, and that the answer is probably opinion-based (and, as @AnonymousPhysicist says, the best answer available is in your question already ...)

Comment: You could always use "&ndash;" - technically, those are all ASCII characters :-)

Comment: Please don't close this question - it doesn't contain the answer, I don't think it is opinion-based, there are other possibilities apart from ASCII, and you might as well do the symbol properly instead of using hyphens

Comment: Prediction: If you submit a paper to the _American Mathematical Monthly_ that refers to the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (with a hyphen), they will leave you're hyphen intact if they publish it, but if it's the _Pacific Journal of Mathematics_, they will make it say Gauss–Bonnet Theorem (with an en-dash).

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is to use MathJax:

```
$\unicode{x2013}$
```

I don't know if it works in all metadata fields, but it does work in some.

Comment: This is one of those things that MathJax does differently from LaTeX.

Comment: One of the dangers seems to be the parsing by other programs like Google Scholar then ...